# Accounting for backspace in UITextField validation using shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm attempting to put validation in a textField to ensure it only contains letters. It works until I press backspace.

As a workaround, I tried to create a `NSMutableCharacterSet` and use `formUnionWithCharacterSet` to add `NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()`. Then I added backspace to it. That's not working either.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {        
    // Limit to Letters & Backspace
    // let charactersAllowed = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
    let charactersAllowed = NSMutableCharacterSet()
    charactersAllowed.formUnionWithCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())
    charactersAllowed.addCharactersInString("\\b")

    if let rangeOfCharactersAllowed = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(charactersAllowed, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) {
        return rangeOfCharactersAllowed.count == string.characters.count
    } else {
        displayAlert("Invalid Character", alertMessage: "Please enter only letters")
        return false
    }
}
```

I've found some old crusty answers in Objective-C, but none of them seem to work for me. Any other suggestions for going to `NSMutableCharacterSet` route for validation?

If it helps, I'm using the simulator and attempting to press the backspace key (delete) in the upper-right-hand corner of the keyboard.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIKeyInput/deleteBackward

Comment: @danh Thank you. I'll set about figuring out what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  let notLetterSet = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet
  let textFieldInvalidCharPosition = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(notLetterSet)

if (textFieldInvalidCharPosition != nil) {
     return false
  } else {
     return true
  }
}
```